# Uploading an image in Rails on Heroku to Imgur via API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, imgur

Is it possible to upload an image using imgur's api via Rails on Heroku (write limitability?)

I was looking at the following gem:

https://github.com/vanntastic/imgur

How would you handle the actual process of pointing to the actual file to upload with the `upload_file` method?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, because you have access to tmp directory. When a file is download on this tmp directory.

Answer (score 0):

Long time no speak.

I literally JUST implemented this: [github commit diff](https://github.com/Trevoke/dfworldgen/commit/32683a1d0fdd3f6161ba09843b2a1321bde7d5db). In my case, since imgur returns a string called 'image_hash' as well as a bunch of other things, I just implemented how to rederive all the other stuff and only stored that small string. I hope this helps! I should consider making this into a full-fledged Rails gem.

[Edit - the code is not perfect, it's version 1!]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the API has changed over the 6 years since this question was posted, but neither of these methods worked for me in mid-2018.

The solution I used is the '[imgur-api](https://rubygems.org/gems/imgur-api)' gem. Sample code below:

```
require 'imgur'

client_id = '1ae88df00f00f00' 

client = Imgur.new(client_id)

image = Imgur::LocalImage.new('test.png', title: 'Test image')

uploaded = client.upload(image)

puts uploaded.link
#=> https://i.imgur.com/bBlMW3X.png
```